# Text alignment disturbed when span have some margin

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment, text-align

I have two `span` on page. I want to vertically align these content but the problem is my first `span` have some margin. and the content of second `span` is too long, So, the text of second `span` is not align with the above `span`. Please see [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DbUS/2/).

In Fiddle : My first span have `100px` margin and you can see the second span is not align with first.

[image]

How can i vertically align both span text using CSS.

**Note: I can't able to change the HTML structure. Please don't suggest me to do it.**

**In the real scenario: I have many blocks without any parent container and each block span have different-different margin. See [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DbUS/18/). And I want each block `second span` align with the span above it.**

Any help would be appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
span.que{
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
span.ans{
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 142px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's working, Can you please provide a sample working fiddle. For me it's look like - http://jsfiddle.net/3DbUS/17/ And the test is not align with above span.

Comment: add margin-left:100px; to span.ans

Comment: ok, but the output is http://jsfiddle.net/3DbUS/20/. You can see in fiddle the text start at second line(span.ans text not started, just after the span.que text).

Comment: Yes, you are. But it want my span.ans text start just after the sapn.que text for example i don't want the text look like this http://jsfiddle.net/3DbUS/21/. Can you please help me to achieve this one?

Comment: Your code looks fine in JsFiddle. But as i mentioned in the Question :  "I have many blocks without any parent container and each block span have different-different margin." it's not working.

Comment: Just put a float on the first span and place it in the other span? That saves a lot of manual coding? And if my answer is not good, why not comment on it?

Comment: as the questioner mentioned that he cannot change the html code

Comment: He could use jquery to manipulate the DOM or either go with my answer. My point is that the questioner seems to have issues, but does not provide feedback to my solution. I also gave another solution in the comments based on his comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `span.ans` `display:inline-block`, by default a span is inline, which means it can't have margins or padding or width or height (it just wraps around the content). Secondly you need to add `margin-left:` with the value of the previous span's margin.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DbUS/19/)